# Session check deny page access ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a login page that is checking users and passwords from an XML file, first I set a string that I will use with sessions then check if user exist

```
string roleCheck = "";

            string userName = node.SelectSingleNode("username").InnerText;
        string passWord = node.SelectSingleNode("password").InnerText;
        string isAdmin = node.SelectSingleNode("role").InnerText;

        if (isAdmin == "admin" && userName == TextBoxUsername.Text && passWord == TextBoxPassword.Text)
        {
            roleCheck = "admin";
            Session["RoleCheck"] = roleCheck;
            Response.Redirect("admin.aspx");
        }
```

Now here is where it fails, it seems I can access admin.aspx even without logging on, I have this in Page_Load on admin.aspx

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (Session["RoleCheck"] == "")
        {
            Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
        }
}
```

Shouldnt this redirect non logged on users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because it is checking whether `Session` is blank string, but here, `Session` is null, i.e not a blank string. Hence condition fails.

You should check `Session` for null rather than empty string.

```
if(Session["RoleCheck"] == null)
{
   // redirect
}
```

Comment: you mean it is not redirecting?

Comment: Yes, I changed the string to null and it still does nothing

Comment: Means your session still exists, clear browser cookies and try again

Comment: Nope.. I added Session.Clear(); to Page_Load on login.aspx, tried it in both Firefox and Chrome, still nothing. Also deleted Cookies and cache.

Comment: Use `Session.Abandon()` instead of `Clear`

Comment: I dont really know what the issue is, it feels as if it skips the Page_Load since its not working, seeing as I now have the variable default at null instead of blank string..

Comment: Did you use `Session.Abandon`?

Comment: Yes I did, in the Page_Load of login.aspx, the logout button takes you to this page so it should clear the session.

Comment: Are you using browser navigation button to move to admin.aspx?

Comment: can you inspect what is the value for session?

Comment: With that you mean like Debug.WriteLine(Session["RoleCheck"]);? Cus the debug doesnt show me anything at all when I write that and run admin.aspx

Comment: I dont know if this is part of the issue, but I just added the Respone.Redirect to all pages on the site and now I cannot get into admin.aspx manually, and neither from logging in, so it seems I got a new issue on my hands. Oh well..

Comment: How do you set session in login.aspx?

Comment: I just fixed it, thanks alot for the help. I missed that I removed the session everytime I visited the loginpage, fixed it with this:

        if (Session["RoleCheck"] != null)
        {
            Session.Abandon();
        }

Answer (score 0):

You need to check just session is null like below code. not check empty or blank.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      if (!IsPostBack)
        {
          if (Session["RoleCheck"] == null)
          {
              Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
          }
        }
  }
```

Comment: This should work, but it does not, its as if it ignores the Page_Load when moving to admin.aspx

Comment: try to add " if (!IsPostBack)" before if condition and check.